# VBA freezes trying to .Close but only on second run

Tags: vba, excel, freeze

So an unexpected error has begun to occur when I run my VBA. It involves opening several excel files and plugging their values into a main Excel file where it then does a bunch of stuff.

It was working fine until I realized that it crashes whenever the user imports the data more than once while the file is open. (So it works perfectly if it runs the first time, or if you exit then run it only once again, but if you run it more than once without exiting first, it freezes)

After using the step method I found where the code freezes and it is when it tries to close one particular excel workbook. It doesn't freeze on any of the other ones for some reason, and it only freezes on this one if you run the import code more than once per session. Any ideas why it might be doing this?

Here is an example of an import that works fine, and then below it is the one that it freezes on. I can only assume it has something to do with the copy - paste method, but with the way the 2nd file is formatted it is the only way I know how to get the values over without a complex import.

---

```
If CbxImport108.Value = True Then

    108.Rows("2:100000").Delete
    'open and transfer 108---------------------------
    Workbooks.Open 108Combination
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Set CurrentBook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)

    If tbx108T.Value = "" Then
        Set CurrentPage = CurrentBook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    Else
        Set CurrentPage = CurrentBook.Sheets(tbx108T.Value)
    End If


    'transfer the data
    TranCounter = 1
    Do While TranCounter < 100 Or CurrentPage.Range("A" + TranCounter).Value <> ""

        TranCounter = TranCounter + 1
    Loop
    Finalcounter = TranCounter

    108.Range("A1:AZ" + Finalcounter).Value = CurrentPage.Range("A1:AZ" + Finalcounter).Value

    CurrentBook.Close
End If


If cbxHS.Value = True Then

    HS.Rows("1:100000").Delete
    'open and transfer HS--------------------------------------
    Workbooks.Open HSCombination
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Set CurrentBook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)

    If tbxHST.Value = "" Then
        Set CurrentPage = CurrentBook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    Else
        Set CurrentPage = CurrentBook.Sheets(tbxHST.Value)
    End If


    'transfer the data
    TranCounter = 1
    Do While TranCounter < 100 Or CurrentPage.Range("A" + TranCounter).Value <> ""

        TranCounter = TranCounter + 1
    Loop
    Finalcounter = TranCounter

    CurrentPage.Range("A1:Z" + Finalcounter).NumberFormat = "@"

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
   CurrentPage.Range("A1:AA" + Finalcounter).Copy
    HS.Range("A1:AA" + Finalcounter).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    CurrentBook.Close

End If
```

---

**EDIT: I didn't intend for people to run this code straight, the only point was to look at it comparing an example of one importation of a file that never freezes and the one that does freeze. The declarations are not included. Sorry for any confusions.**

Comment: Can you post an actual working example? The snippet you've provided has syntax errors and is out of context of a particular procedure. 108.[something] isn't a valid variable name, I'm not sure how you're even getting it to run as it's a syntax error on my end.

Answer (score 0):

May be using the currentpage with cell reference is causing it to redirection of different excel files when you run it second time

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to fix the glitch even though I still don't understand /why/ it was doing this nor why this worked: After it finishes copy and pasting, but before it is told to close the book, I added in "Application.CutCopyMode = True" and the freezing stopped. I have been able to run the import code over 5 times in a row now without issues. This explains why it kept crashing on this workbook and none of the other ones.

Thanks for the help everyone!

---

```
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    CurrentPage.Range("A1:AA" + Finalcounter).Copy
    Haystack.Range("A1:AA" + Finalcounter).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    CurrentBook.Close
```

---